# If you reset the password for a user can other users access the EFS encrypted files?

Tags: windows-7, security, ntfs, efs

I have a user that's forgotten their password. I can log in and reset it but there were some EFS encrypted files. I can still access those files because my login is the security group.

If I reset the password for the user I know they won't be able to access the encrypted files but will I? That is, does a password reset just effect the login or does it effect ALL files the user may have been the OWNER of?